# Errors in setting up HBase on Distributed Hadoop, ZooKeeperServer not running

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I'm trying to set up HBase on Hadoop and have been follow various great tutorials online by [Michael G. Noll](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/) and [here](http://openwires.blogspot.com/p/hbase-multiple-node-setup-guide.html). Basically all is fine, my Hdfs and MapRed works well on the web interface it shows that I have 2 nodes (my NameNode is both a NameNode and a DataNode but that's just for testing purposes).

When I got to the point of installing HBase, thats where I meet problems, I get lots of different errors. The latest one I have is on the log file in my slave node

```
INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Closed socket connection for client /10.2.xx.xx:43089 (no session established for client)
INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn: Exception causing close of session 0x0 due to java.io.IOException: ZooKeeperServer not running
```

But when I type in

```
$ zkServer.sh status
```

It says shows the mode that both machines are running in!
Anyone has any idea what is this problem. Or does any one know of another guide/tutorial that I can follow to set this up? I've tried following the HBase documentation on setting up HBase on a distributed HDFS but it doesn't work too.

Thanks for any help offered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are both the zookeepers servers configured in a Qorum? If so have they managed to connect to one another and vote on who's the leader (this should all be in the logs for both servers).

Zookeeper may be running, but if they can't communicate with one another (firewall rules or miss configuration for example), then zookeeper will not accept in coming client connections

Comment: Weird now I can't even start Zookeeper on my own usingzkServer.sh start. Do you know if I can set up a distributed HBase on HDFS with HBase managing Zookeeper? (ie in the hbase-env config export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true)

Comment: Now I have another problem. I'm breaking the problem down and trying to set up a Zookeeper in a replicated mode (2 machines, I'm just testing) but it seems that the machine that I run zkServer.sh start on starts up in standalone mode, where as the other remote machine does not start Zookeeper at all? Do I have to manually start it up?

Comment: have you followed the instructions on http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.3/zookeeperStarted.html#sc_RunningReplicatedZooKeeper for Running Replicated Zookeeper?

Comment: Or http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.3/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_zkMulitServerSetup

Comment: Yes I've followed them pretty much exactly. zoo.cfg contents, myid files everything is okay. Do I have to run zookeeper using this: $ java -cp zookeeper.jar:lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:conf \ org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain zoo.cfg? or can I start it by using zkServer.sh start

Comment: When I try running the $ java -cp ...... conf \ org.apache.... I have a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/apache/zookeeper/server/quorum/QuorumPeerMain. Does it matter that I am using Cloudera's version of zookeeper?
Anyway thanks a lot for your patience and help thus far! Appreciate it alot

Comment: Latest update is that I can run Zookeeper (I have no idea how I did it, zkServer.sh status just returned Leader and Follower on the two machines suddenly), but HBase doesn't seem to be able to make use of the ZK that I set up. On the HBase regionserver node log it says something like: Problem connecting to Master server at localhost:60000. Seems like the region server is trying to connect to itself to find HMaster where I clearly provided an IP address for Master. Trying to solve this problem now.

Comment: I solved it buy commenting out the ipv6 lines in my /etc/hosts file. and also all other 127.0.0.1 references (except the one that says 127.0.0.1 MachineName)